# How to fix double-encoded UTF8 characters in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis, encoding

I have a dataset (shapefile) with the same problem as the post below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436594/how-to-fix-double-encoded-utf8-characters-in-an-utf-8-table

*"A previous LOAD DATA INFILE was run under the assumption that the CSV file is latin1-encoded. During this import the multibyte characters were interpreted as two single character and then encoded using utf-8 (again).
This double-encoding created anomalies like ÃƒÂ± instead of ñ."*

However, the solution given is in mysql and not postgres, i tried it on postgres and it didn't work, just worked on mysql:

```
UPDATE tablename SET
    field = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(field USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);
```

I need to import and fix this shapefile using postgres because I will need to use postgis to do various spatial analyzes.

How can I solve this using postgis?

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty similar in PostgreSQL:

```
convert_from(convert_to(textcol, 'LATIN1'), 'UTF8')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I tried this:
SELECT(
 convert_from(
  convert_to(nome_area, 'LATIN1'), 'UTF8'))
 FROM sigef_sp_multiparte_latin1;

Give a error: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc3 0x3f
SQL state: 22021

Comment: Then that string is not "doubly UTF-8 encoded".